# Multiplicative Identitiy Axiom

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am reading through ["The Art of Proof"](http://math.sfsu.edu/beck/aop.html) and Axiom 1.3 says

> There exists an integer 1 such that $1 \neq 0$ and whenever $m \in \mathbb Z$, $m \times 1 = m$.

Why is it necessary to state that $1 \neq 0$?

Comment: What other axioms are there? If none of the other axioms make it clear that $1 \not = 0$, then this would be a non-trivial addition to the axiom. If, however, from the other axioms you can infer that $1 \not = 0$, then it would not be necessary to make it part of the axiom, and just prove it as a theorem. But it all depends on what those other axioms are saying.

Comment: The axiom right before this one says "There exists an integer 0 such that whenever $m \in \mathbb Z$, $m + 0 = 0$".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [pdf of the book](http://math.sfsu.edu/beck/papers/aop.noprint.pdf)

So basically the axioms are:

$\forall x \forall y \ x + y = y + x$

$\forall x \forall y \forall z \ (x + y) + z = x + (y + z)$

$\forall x \forall y \forall z \ x \cdot ( y + z) = (x\cdot y) + (x \cdot z)$

$\forall x \forall y \ x \cdot y = y \cdot x$

$\forall x \forall y \forall z \ (x \cdot y) \cdot z = x \cdot (y \cdot z)$

$\forall x \ x + 0 = x$

$1 \not = 0 \land \forall x \ x \cdot 1 = x$

$\forall x \exists y \ x + y = 0$

$\forall x (x \not = 0 \rightarrow \exists y \ x \cdot y = 1)$

Now, note that if you take away the $1 \not = 0$, then you can satisfy all axioms by a domain that contains exactly $1$ element, denoted by $0$. And indeed, $1 \not = 0$ would be false under that interpretation. So, $1 \not = 0$ adds something concrete to the axioms.

Comment: Then 0 and 1 are up to this point just variables like x, y and z and only the statement $1 \neq 0$ tells me that they are different and thus the domain must have at least 2 elements?

Comment: @jruota Almost:  $0$ and $1$ are individual constant symbols, rather than variables. So, any interpretation will map that constant to a specific object ... but different interpretations may map it to different objects. And any interpretation may map different constants to the same object ... hence you could have an interpretation where $0$ and $1$ are both interpreted as the same one object. And indeed, by saying $1 \not = 0$, we force any interpretation to map $0$ to a different object than $1$, and hence there must be at least two objects ... still a long shot from the real numbers, but hey!

Answer (score 1):

If $1=0$, then
$$
a=a\cdot1=a\cdot0=0
$$
for all $a$, since
$$
a\cdot0=a\cdot(0+0)=a\cdot0+a\cdot0.
$$